# How do I pass variables to Python Lambda from AWS API

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have tried searching but my googlefu is failing me.

I have a basic python lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    foo = event['bar']
    print(foo)
```

I then try and do a POST, like this in curl:

```
curl -X POST https://correctaddress.amazonaws.com/production/test \
-H 'x-api-key: CORRECTKEY' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-H 'bar: Hello World' \
```

This fails `KeyError: 'bar'` probably because what I think I am passing as event['bar'] is not being passed as such.

I have tried `event['body']['bar']` which also fails.

If I do `event['querystringparameters']['bar']` it will work if I use a GET such as:

```
curl -X POST https://correctaddress.amazonaws.com/production/test?bar=HelloWorld -H 'x-api-key: CORRECTKEY'
```

I know I am missing something fundamental about the event dictionary, and what it pulls from for a POST, but I can't seem to find the right documentation (unsure of if it would be in API or Lambda's documentation).

My eventual goal is to be able to write something in python using Requests like this:

```
import requests, json

url = "https://correctaddress.amazonaws.com/production/test"
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'x-api-key': "CORRECTKEY"}
data = {}
data['bar'] = "Hello World"
res = requests.put(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are executing your curl command.

You are using the -H (--header) argument to add your parameter. But you are expecting a JSON post request.

To do so change your curl statement to something like this:

```
curl -X POST https://correctaddress.amazonaws.com/production/test \
-H 'x-api-key: CORRECTKEY' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"bar":"Hello World"}' \
```

This will make curl do a post request with the appropriate body.

In your Python you can get the postdata as a dictionary using some code similar to this:

```
postdata = json.loads(event['body'])
```

You should add some error checking for invalid JSON, other request types (e.g. GET), etc.

Comment: that didn't work...
`curl -X POST https://correctaddress.amazonaws.com/production/test -H 'x-api-key: CORRECTKEY' -H 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"bar":"Hello World"}'`

I still get errors.

if I use `foo = event['body']['bar']` it tells me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

If I use `foo = event['bar']` it tells me `KeyError: 'bar'`

Comment: Event['body'] is a string containing the JSON data. You can decode it using the json module. json.loads(...)

Comment: yup, that's what I ended up doing. Would it be appropriate for you to edit your answer and add that? Maybe it'll help someone in the future as well.